# How does SQL Server break down view code and pick the right tables to extract?

Tags: sql-server, join, view

I encountered a problem regarding views in SQL Server 2017.

I'm running a query against a view which has multiple underlying tables behind. Besides tables involved in `SELECT` clause, other tables also get logical read by SQL Server, and I want to know why.

Here is scenario:

```
/*******************************************************/
CREATE VIEW v_test
AS
SELECT 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col3,
    b.col4,
    c.col5,
    c.col6,
    d.col7,
    d.col8,
    e.col9,
    e.col10,
    f.col11,
    f.col12,
    g.col13,
    g.col14
FROM  a
LEFT JOIN b
LEFT JOIN c
LEFT JOIN d
LEFT JOIN e
LEFT JOIN f
LEFT JOIN g

/*********************************************************/
SELECT col1, col2
FROM V_test
```

- The col1 col2 should only be pulled out from tbl_a.=>means, logical reads should only read table a.
- However, the logical reads turns out to read more tables than tbl_a. In an scenario I got, it reads tbl_a thru tbl_g.

Why is this?

Comment: Of course it reads the other tables. It needs to know if any rows are removed or duplicated based on the join predicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that rows from table A get eliminated or duplicated depending on all join conditions.
So to know how many rows should be returned all join conditions has to be evaluated in most cases.